# I can send E-Mails but not receive E-Mails.. | CentOs - Docker - poste.io

Tags: linux, email, dns, centos, firewalld

I run a Server on CentOs 7 with FirewallD, on there i run Docker with Poste.io Mailserver. (SQLite, Dovecot, NGiNX, Haraka, RSPAMD, ClamAV, Roundcube, Z-Push)

Soo my problem is i can´t receive E-Mails, but i can send E-Mails without any problems.
I have opend all Ports manually in FirewallD 
*(Screenshot of FirewallD List: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih70k.png )*
but still only getting to work Port 25 Outbound but not Port 25 Inbound. As seen in the Serverstatus from poste.io Adminpanel
*(Screenshot of Serverstatus in the poste.io Adminpanel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzyPh.png )*

*(And i dont know why it can´t connect to itself via IPv4...)*

The DNS seems to be working with the MX and A records. It finds the Server but it activly refuses to reveive it. I tested it via the https://ismyemailworking.com/AdvancedTest/

Log from the test:

```
01/16/2020 09:53:23 - [IsMyEmailWorking.com email test started]
01/16/2020 09:53:24 - [Querying DNS for responsible mail servers for 'l***.at']
01/16/2020 09:53:24 - [Starting DNS Session]
01/16/2020 09:53:24 - [RFC 5321 5. The lookup first attempts to locate an MX record associated with the name. If a CNAME record is found, the resulting name is processed as if it were the initial name. If no MX records are found, but an A RR is found, the A RR is treated as if it was associated with an implicit MX RR, with a preference of 0, pointing to that host.]
01/16/2020 09:53:24 - [Trying to get MX Records for 'l***.at']
01/16/2020 09:53:25 - [Found MX Record 'mail.l***.at' Preference '10']
01/16/2020 09:53:25 - [Found 1 MX Records]
01/16/2020 09:53:25 - [Searching Found MX Records for Host Records]
01/16/2020 09:53:25 - [MX Record 'mail.l***.at' Did not include any Host records. Queueing 'mail.l***.at' for further resolution.]
01/16/2020 09:53:25 - [Performing Additional Queries for Host records for MX Records that are queued for further resolution]
01/16/2020 09:53:25 - [Found an A Host Record for 'mail.l***.at' of '37.252.***.***']
01/16/2020 09:53:25 - [Completed Additional Queries for Host records]
01/16/2020 09:53:25 - [DNS Session completed]
01/16/2020 09:53:25 - [Found 1 responsible mail servers for 'l***.at']
01/16/2020 09:53:29 - [Selected target email server to test 'mail.l***.at/37.252.***.***']
01/16/2020 09:53:30 - [Starting SMTP Session]
01/16/2020 09:53:30 - [Attempting to connect to 'mail.l***.at/37.252.***.***']
01/16/2020 09:53:30 - [Connecting to 37.252.***.***:25.]
01/16/2020 09:53:32 - [Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 37.252.***.***:25]
```

Comment: Insecure Send / Receive is done through Port 25 Send and Port 110 Receive. Exchange has security outside of ports to secure it. Receive also may be secure 995/993.

Comment: I can´t receive a Mail, sent via gmail or MS Exchage Server. Both try to connect via Port 25, all i get back is a Error Message, that the server Refused to connect via 37.252.***.***:25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know that on the OS Postfix was running from the startup...
It was catching all incomming from Port 25.

Now i disabled Postfix and can receive E-Mails.

Comment: Happy you found a solution, but please do not edit your question to add “SOLVED!” to it. If you have self-solved a question post an answer like you have here and — when the system allows you to — be sure it check it off as the answer.